# Can I run a while() at the same time as a switch(messages) statement? (c++)

Tags: c++, windows, while-loop

I have a simple program.  It looks like this:

```
bool i = fasle;

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hThisInstance,
                   HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                   LPSTR lpszArgument,
                   int nCmdShow)
{
    /*COMMENT TO REPRESENT WNDCLASSEX STUFF*/

    return messages.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(message)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
            CreateWindow(
                TEXT("button"),TEXT("Activate"),
                WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
                10,
                100,
                100,
                50,
                hwnd,
                (HMENU) 1,
                NULL, NULL
                );
            CreateWindow(
                TEXT("button"),TEXT("Deactivate"),
                WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
                10,
                250,
                100,
                50,
                hwnd,
                (HMENU) 2,
                NULL, NULL
                );
            break;
        case WM_COMMAND:
            if(LOWORD(wParam) == 1){
                i = true;
            }
            if(LOWORD(wParam) == 2){
                i = false;
            }
            break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage (0);
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc (hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I want a while statement to run no matter what.  The loop looks like this:

```
while(1)
{
    if(i == true)
    {
        /*DO STUFF*/
    }
}
```

Where can I add my loop into my code to make it run forever?

Comment: What part are you getting confused on? Running code in a while loop with a tautology will cause it to run "forever", and you've already written out a tautology.

Comment: And where is the while loop shown in your code? Post a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Besides, the code shown above couldn't possibly even compile.

Comment: `fasle`? I don't think that compiles.

Answer (score 2):

> Where can I add my loop into my code to make it run forever?

***In a different thread.***

Sorry, but this is a fact of life with GUIs.  The Win32 GUI programming model is event driven, and in event driven systems you cannot do long-running operations on the GUI thread, because then the GUI thread never gets the chance to process any messages.

So, you have to move your endless- (or even just long-) running loop in a different thread.

However, this is quite likely an X-Y Problem. (http://xyproblem.info/)